# Needs Id to be updated on record field

Tags: apex, trigger, update, id

I have created a trigger which creates New Event when a record in inserted in a staging object.

I need the Event Id to be updated in Staging object field..There is no lookup/MD between 2 objects in this case
The following is the code below:

```
list<Event_Staging__c>Eventsup = new list<Event_Staging__c>();
    for(Event e:insertedEvents){

     Event_Staging__c a = new Event_Staging__c(Meeting_UID__c = e.description);
     a.Event_ID__c = e.Id;

     Eventsup.add(a);
    }

  update Eventsup;
```

Comment: what is the exact problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. Is it working fine? As this post looks like a information about what are you doing. Not a question.

Comment: There is a question in there you just have to really look for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is

- use an **External Id** to create a sObject

  ```
  Event_Staging__c a = new Event_Staging__c(Meeting_UID__c = e.description);
  ```
- populate the Event ID for that record

  ```
   a.Event_ID__c = e.Id;
  ```
- and update the sObject.

  ```
  update Eventsup;
  ```

The External ID is the same on both the event and the sObject.

if that is the case, you are possibly getting the error *"Id not specified in an update call"*

In order to do what you are trying to do you need to use **Upsert**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm

Your DML line should be:

```
upsert Eventsup Meeting_UID__c
```

Which will update / insert the sObject records based on the External ID